# Mok Management steps to take?

Tags: dual-boot, reboot, secure-boot

After the first rebook I get to Mok Management blue screen. My issue is that I don't have the same choices as any other forum/video that I have seen.

My choices are:

Continue boot
  Reset Mok
  Enroll key from disk
  Enroll hash from disk

If I select enroll Key from Disk, I get a choice of system or ESP with text at the top saying:

> The selected key will be enrolled into the MOK database. This means any binaries signed with it will be run without prompt. Remember to make sure it is a genuine key before enrolling it.

I am not sure how to proceed, if anyone knows, that would be great. I originally had the option of Enroll MOK, instead of reset MOK, which I know now is the correct option. What I don't know is if I hit reset MOK, will it cause a problem, or reset it so it has the enroll MOK choice again? I also found out, if you don't do anything, it times out, reloads Windows, and then restart computer and go to boot screen brings me back to MOK Management.

Comment: The option `Continue boot` continues to boot Linux without touching the MOK.